# Remove jquery autocomplete hi lighting

Tags: jquery

below is link for basic jquery autocomplete 
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Below is the code which I have added to make the searched character to become bold in suggestion list.

```
$.ui.autocomplete.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
     item.label = item.label.replace(new RegExp("(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(this.term) + ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>");
     return $("<li></li>")
                .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
                .appendTo(ul);
    };
```

But on hover the hovered text is hi lighted in blue. But I  want to remove that hi light. Kindly suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply your css to `ui-menu-item-wrapper`:-

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item-wrapper:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #000;
}
```

if you want to remove the border also then add:-

```
border-color: transparent;
```